# How to send mail with Sinatra using Pony?

Tags: ruby, forms, email, sinatra, pony

I am having trouble sending email using the contact form I built in Sinatra. I'm using the Pony gem. For some reason I get this error saying 'No such file exist-which sendmail'. I have installed 'sendmail' and I'm still having the same issue. I'm open to any suggestions. The code is below:

Contact form

```
<form action='/' id='contact' name='contact' method='post' novalidate='novalidate' >

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="input-wrap">
                        <input type="text" class='form-control' name='name' id='name' placeholder='NAME'>
                        </div>

                        <br>

                    <div class="input-wrap">
                        <input type="email" class='form-control' name='mail' id='mail' placeholder='EMAIL'>
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <div class="input-wrap">
                        <input type="text" class='form-control' name='subject' id='subject' placeholder='SUBJECT'>

                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <div class="input-wrap">
                        <textarea placeholder='MESSAGE' class='form-control' name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <input type='submit' value='SEND' id='button'>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

main.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'bundler/setup'



get '/' do 
File.read('index.html')
end

post '/' do
require 'pony'
name  = params[:name]
mail = params[:mail]
subject = params[:subject]
body  = params[:body]


Pony.mail(:to => 'mjstokes1986@att.net', :from => '#{name}', :subject => '#{subject}', :body => '#{body}')

# File.read('index.html')

redirect '/success'

end

get '/success' do
File.read('success.html')
end
```

Comment: Copy and paste the full error message.  What is the output of `$ which sendmail`?

Comment: Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory - which sendmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to tell `Pony.mail` method where to find your `sendmail`. You can find your sendmail location using `which sendmail`. (If this doesn't return anything then you just haven't installed the sendmail correctly).

```
Pony.mail({
  ...
  :via_options => { :location  => '/path/to/your/sendmail'}
})
```

Comment: I've downloaded and install sendmail. How do I find the path?

Comment: Type `which sendmail` in your shell (if you are using Mac or Linux). It should return something like `/usr/sbin/sendmail`. If it doesn't return anything then there were some problems with the installation.

Comment: This is how I got mine setup

    `Pony.mail({
  :to => 'mjstokes1986@att.net', 
  :from => '#{name}',
  :subject => '#{subject}',
  :body => '#{body}',
  :via_options => {:location => '/c/sendmail/./sendmail'}
  })`

Comment: Is the `/c/sendmail/./sendmail` the result of `which sendmail`, the path looks weird?

Comment: That what it returned when I typed `which sendmail`